# Apache configuration files changing upon restart

Tags: apache, ssl, config

I haven't had to work with Apache since the nineties.  Things have changed a bit.  :)  Anyway, I need to remediate a bunch of vulnerabilities that require me to alter the ssl.config.  In particular, I added new certs (i just renamed them to overcome the problem) and the SSLCipherSuite.  Every time I change the SSLCipherSuite to HIGH, and restart the httpd service, the original line returns in the ssl.conf file.  I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What distribution is that http server operated on, assuming that you are using a Linux based operating system?

Comment: This is a RHEL5 server.  I know it's old.  We can't update it because of the apps and support contract for those apps.

Comment: Check if there is some hook in the service control script performing the startup which loads some blueprint files. I have little experience with RHEL, always preferred SLES, but some older distributions had such "shadow setup layer".

Comment: Is this site for a company or personal? If it's for your company it's highly possible they have something like CFEngine, Puppet, or Chef controlling the Apache configuration file.

Comment: There was actually a script that a vendor put in which used sed to append the configuration.  A few lines commented out, and it's good to go.